# Highest date that comes up in every group

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with this set of Covid-19 Data:

```
daten <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openZH/covid_19/master/COVID19_Fallzahlen_CH_total.csv")
datum <- format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d") %>%
  as.Date()
```

What I'm trying to do is to group the df by "abbreviation_canton_and_fl" and then find the value in "date" that is closest to sys.Date() but also comes up in every group.

I have tried this to find the closest date to "datum":

```
which(abs(daten$date-datum) == min(abs(daten$date-datum)))
```

And this works too:

```
x <- daten %>%
  group_by(abbreviation_canton_and_fl)
```

But I cannot find a way to stick the two together so that I get what I need.

Comment: Perhaps `daten %>% group_by(abbreviation_canton_and_fl) %>% slice(findInterval(datum, date))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `findInterval`

```
library(dplyr)
daten %>% 
   group_by(abbreviation_canton_and_fl) %>%
   slice(findInterval(datum, date))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two conditions using `group_by` with `slice` and `which.min` :

```
library(dplyr)
daten %>% 
    group_by(abbreviation_canton_and_fl) %>% 
    slice(which.min(abs(date - datum)))
```

Perhaps, this is more closer to your attempt :

```
daten %>%
  group_by(abbreviation_canton_and_fl) %>%
  filter(abs(date - datum) == min(abs(date - datum)))
```